# List of equations in MAGMA

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, computer-algebra-systems, magma-cas

I have some integer $n$, some ambient affine space $\mathbb{A}^n$, and a list $L$ of equations $f_{ij}$ cutting out a variety $X$ in the ambient space. I have problems defining the list $L$ correctly. My code
looks as follows:

- define the ambient space
- for i,j in [1..n] define the $f_{ij}$

this works as it should; I get the correct equations. Then (outside the for loop defining the $f_{ij}$) I define my list L by

- L:=[$f_{ij}$ : i,j in [1..n]];

when I print L, it has the correct number of elements, but all elements are $f_{11}$ rather than the $f_{ij}$. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, naively it looks correct, but maybe I don't properly understand how lists work in MAGMA. Thanks for your help!

Complete code:

> Q:=Rationals();
>
> n:=2;
>
> A:=AffineSpace(Q, n^2);
>
> for i,j in [1..n] do
>
> fij := 0;
>
> for k in [1..n] do
>
> fij +:= A.(k+(i-1)*n)*A.(k+(j-1)*n);
>
> end for;
>
> end for;
>
> L:=[fij : i,j in [1..n]];

Comment: Could you post some complete code? It would be easier to understand the issue then.

Comment: @AlexJBest you are right, thanks. I just posted the complete code. I suppose part of the problem is that the $f_{ij}$ might not be defined outside the for loop, but strangely enough MAGMA doesn't complain about my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you declare a variable called `fij` but this is only a name to magma, it doesn't know that you want different variables for different i,j so each loop you overwrite `fij` with the next one and at the end you make a list with this one variable $n^2$ times.

One way to do what you want is to add each `f` to `L` as you go along using `Append` like so:

```
Q:=Rationals();

n:=2;

L := [];

A:=AffineSpace(Q, n^2);

for i,j in [1..n] do
    f := 0;
    for k in [1..n] do
        f +:= A.(k+(i-1)*n)*A.(k+(j-1)*n);
    end for;
    Append(~L, f);
end for;
print L;
```

Comment: makes sense, thanks a lot!